# Google can no longer fetch pages after successful URL rewrites using an .htaccess file

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

I tried to rewrite my URLs so they no longer have the `.html` extension. But when I did this (successfully) Google can no longer crawl my pages when I use "Fetch as Google". Instead, it returns `404` errors and says they're unreachable.

This is what I have in my *.htacess* file:

```
Options +Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great, and if I type the URL in a browser's address bar it takes me there. However, Google is still returning `404` errors.

I think it has something to do with the above code rewriting it to `www.example.com` while Google is requesting `http://www.example.com`. I'm not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: I am confused by the last sentence. Can you clarify it for me??

Comment: Yah sorry, in google webmaster tools the url that it fetches is "http:// www.example.com/whatever" but my redirect rules seem to redirect everything to "www.example.com/whatever" ignoring the "http://". Im not sure but I think that is proving problematic for the fetch as google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are over thinking this. I am really confused over all your code.

One of the things I am finding these days is that people are using example code that is already unnecessarily complicated. As well, people seem to select {???} that offers too much instead of the narrowest selection. Often these things only require 2 lines or 3 at the most and only one RewriteRule. Always seek the most simplest options when doing any regular expression. Otherwise you run a risk of unintended consequences.

Now I may be assuming too much. You may have been trying to do two things and my tired brain could not figure this out. Please let me know.

I tested this here and it did what you described:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/%1 [R,L]
```

Remove the RewriteBase, and the RewriteCond(s) and RewriteRule(s) that you are using. RewriteBase is not necessary.

If you need more, please give a comment and I can/will be happy to update the answer. If I missed what you are trying to do, please let me know.

Comment: Forgot to say this worked perfectly, as you suspected I was using example code that was intended to accomplish the same thing and as far as I could tell was, except when googlebot got to it.

Comment: @user2070057 Thanks for the feed back! There seems to be a new wave/trend in the past year or so where a lot of example code is posted on-line that is overly complicated. It is not only confused, but confusing. When it comes to regular expressions, and I code using regex nearly everyday, simplicity is king. The simpler it can be made the more likely it will be reliable and not have exceptions that escape the expression.